# 3D Display Technology Technique

Tags: refraction, vision, light-emitting-diodes

I was randomly reminded of 3D TVs/Nintendo 3DS and was wondering about how they work without glasses as I was already familiar with 3D with glasses. Everything I found online seemed to be about using convex prisms to disperse light or stereoscopy, which has limited angles and focus issues.

Would it not be feasible to have a layer in front of the color filter that can re-orient the emitted light? Even if the orientation layer could only 'bend' the entire display one common angle at a time, you could sweep (yes this would hurt the refresh rate). The color filter itself would not display a traditional image, rather it is used to intelligently color the vector of light to match what the real 3D scene would be sending out from that spot/angle. This would certainly require an optimized video format + software.

I know for photonic computers they developed a material whose optical properties change with charge, so it seems like this isn't strictly impossible.

Just wondering if this technique is sensible/already exists and what it is called.

**EDIT**

Just realized I'm basically describing a lenticular display that uses a magic material to do the refraction dynamically instead of analog (baked into the display).